# return Socialite::driver('google')->user(); is not working

Tags: php, web, google-oauth, laravel-9, laravel-socialite

I want to try google login in laravel. So at first for checking purpose i want to return Socialite::driver('google')->user(); this. Here i am adding all of part of my code with error
Controller:

```
 public function redirectToGoogle()
{
    return Socialite::driver('google')->redirect();
}

public function handleGoogleCallback()
{

    $user = Socialite::driver('google')->user();
    return $user;

}
```

route:

```
Route::get('authorized/google', [CustomerController::class, 'redirectToGoogle']);
Route::get('authorized/google/callback', [CustomerController::class, 'handleGoogleCallback']);
```

View:

```
 <a href="{{ url('authorized/google') }}" class="google-btn">
                        <i class="fab fa-google"></i> Register with Google
                    </a>
```

Also added this in service.php correctly

```
 'google' => [
    'client_id' => '<id>',
    'client_secret' => '<secret>',
    'redirect' => 'http://localhost:8000/authorized/google/callback',
],
```

When user click on that button it successfully redirect to choose google account.But whenever i choosed an account then this error occur
I tried a lot by seeing lots of solution in google and chatgpt but it is not working

[image]